# Is there a tool to evaluate database designs

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, database-performance

I am working on quite a large database system and was wondering if there is a tool to evaluate a database design.  Essentially I need something that would run through a database, point out slow downs and issue areas.  Even better would be if the tool could look at statistics on already running databases and offer suggestions.

Comment: I guess I should have stated that we are using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, you will benefit from the [Database Engine Tuning Advisor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173494.aspx).  Quoted directly from TechNet, here are the capabilities:

> Recommend the best mix of indexes for databases by using the query
>   optimizer to analyze queries in a workload.
>
> Recommend aligned or non-aligned partitions for databases referenced
>   in a workload.
>
> Recommend indexed views for databases referenced in a workload.
>
> Analyze the effects of the proposed changes, including index usage,
>   query distribution among tables, and query performance in the
>   workload.
>
> Recommend ways to tune the database for a small set of problem
>   queries.
>
> Allow you to customize the recommendation by specifying advanced
>   options such as disk space constraints.
>
> Provide reports that summarize the effects of implementing the
>   recommendations for a given workload.
>
> Consider alternatives in which you supply possible design choices in
>   the form of hypothetical configurations for Database Engine Tuning
>   Advisor to evaluate.

Comment: Thanks, that is just what I needed.  Side note, we are using azure as well, and it doesn't work with azure yet.  Just have to pull and hit the local for a bit.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what database you are using, but of course a good first start in MySQL is often to use the EXPLAIN command:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html

There are a collection of third party applications that assist with database tuning with MySQL. such as [MONyog](http://www.webyog.com/doc/index.php).